# Always missing one row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk

I created a UITableView programmatically (not using a XIB).  It reads a *.plist file containing an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary objects.  The problem I am experiencing is this: When I display the objects in the UITableView, it never shows the object at row zero.  I know this because I get the following NSLog output:

```
2009-06-01 10:02:34.566 Color[784:20b] array count = 4
2009-06-01 10:02:34.570 Color[784:20b] row = 3: Air
2009-06-01 10:02:34.570 Color[784:20b] row = 2: Earth
2009-06-01 10:02:34.571 Color[784:20b] row = 1: Water
2009-06-01 10:02:34.571 Color[784:20b] row = 0: Fire
```

What I will see, in this case, is a table with Water, Earth, and Air (but no Fire).  If I add another object, then Fire will appear but the new object will not.  Therefore, it is *always* the object at row 0.

Here is some relevant code:

```
@interface LoadViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *loadedObjects;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.loadedObjects = [self getCurrentData];
    NSLog(@"array count = %d", [self.loadedObjects count]); 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.loadedColors count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString *Identifier = @"Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Identifier] autorelease];
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *obj = [self.loadedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.text = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"row = %d: %@", row, [obj objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    return cell;
}
```

In the code snippets you can also see my output to NSLog.

When I had populated UITableViews from a NIB I had never experienced this problem.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should we assume that the separate loadedObjects and loadedColors are a typo here?

Comment: Except for that typo, this seems good code. I'd start by switching out the cell.text assignment for something static, or something like "Cell %d". That way you can isolate the UITableView part from the loadedObjects and see which is the problem.

Comment: Maybe add a breakpoint on cellForRowAtIndexPath and verify your 'loadedObjects' property still contains what you're expecting it to contain?

Comment: Sorry, I genericized it for the posting.  The typo does not exist in the code.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: I stepped through using the debugger and verified that it steps through four times, once for each element in the NSMutableArray.  I checked the value of cell.text to make sure it correlated with the output to NSLog.  Even the "missing" object shows up in the debugger and the logs, but when time comes to display the table, row 0 is missing.  Could it be a configurable parameter like a Header row or something?

Answer (score 1):

I feel kind of dumb, but maybe this could be useful to someone else...

What I failed to mention in my description (because I didn't think it was relevant) was the fact that I also instantiated a UINavigationBar to have an Edit button in the upper-right corner.  In a nutshell, the nav bar was obscuring the first record in the table.

The reason why I couldn't see this is because I did this:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:navBar];
```

and what that did was to "stick" the navBar to the table, so scrolling could not reveal the missing row.  When I changed that line to:

```
[self.appDelegate.window addSubview:navBar];
```

I could drag the first record out from under the navBar because they then become sibling views.

I apologize for the misplaced question.

Comment: Why are you adding a navigation bar manually instead of using the UINavigationController which adds a nav bar to conained view controllers automatically?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix a big problem in my first Swift/UITableView attempt. I could never see the first few rows of my UITableView because I made it taller than its ViewController!